# Applying Catalog Price Rule to Advanced Pricing

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules, tiered-pricing, advanced-pricing

I am new to Magento so I apologize in advance if this has already been asked and answered (if so, can you please point me there?)

We are running Magento 2.3.5 Community Edition.

We have multiple Customer Groups (say, Group 1, Group 2, Group 3, etc.). For the same SKU, we have different price for each of these Customer Groups (Price 1, Price 2, Price 3, etc.). These different prices are specified in the Advanced Pricing.

We now want to run a 10% OFF promotion for that SKU such that each customer group gets 10% of their individual group price. So, for example, Group 1 discounted price will be Price 1 less 10%, Group 2's price will be Price 2 less 10% and so on.

Is this possible to do from Admin Panel using Catalog Price Rule? I tried creating a rule there but it only applies to the General or NOT LOGGED IN group; it doesn't apply to other Customer Groups.

Or, is there a module available that will let me do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: working fine for me, could you should your settings? Also, it's cart price rule, not catalog rule

Comment: @Jimmy The cart price rule works fine for us, too. However, we need Catalog Price Rule to work. Cart Price Rule is not useful in our use case because we are looking to only discount specific items that qualify, not discount the whole cart. 

Let's say a Golf Shirt qualifies for 10% discount but a Track Pant does not. So, if you put both Golf Shirt and Track Pant in their cart, it'd be wrong to apply 10% off cart price rule for both items. Also, Golf Shirt has different prices for each Customer Group and we need to be able to give 10% off individua; customer group price.